# Why some folders do not get pushed on github?

Tags: github, push, commit

I'm fairly new to github and when I was trying to push my code for version control I noticed that some folders appear empty.

Now, these folders are also github repos that I got using git clone. is this the issue? and if so, how do I solve it?

thanks,

Comment: Can you describe that with a screenshot ? Its really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You can't nest git repos like that.  You should use a package manager (like npm) to manage dependencies.  Or learn about submodules.